# Better understanding of how control.InvokeRequired works

Tags: c#, winforms

First, I have Windows app with a couple of methods.

One within main Form class:

```
private void generate_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerationThreads nw = new GenerationThreads();
            nw.control = testlabel;
           // nw.DelegateUpdater();

               Thread tr1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(nw.DelegateUpdater));
               tr1.Start();
               Thread.Sleep(100);
```

and two in GenerationThreads class:

```
public void DelegateUpdater()
        {
            string envelope = "*Envelope was brought safely.*";
            string iterations = "";
            
           for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++)
            {
                iterations = iterations + x.ToString() + " iterations done.\n";
                PassToLegate(iterations);
                Thread.Sleep(400);
            }
            PassToLegate(iterations + envelope);
        }

private void PassToLegate(string text)    
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired == true)
    { 
        var hat = new Legate(PassToLegate);
        string message = text + " (Legate involved)";

        control.Invoke(hat, new object[] {message});
    }

    if (control.InvokeRequired == false)
    {
        control.Text = text + " (Legate not involved)";
    }
}
```

When DelegateUpdater() is called directly after pressing button, like in commented part - without making a new thread - it just nicely executes three for() spins, displaying them all at once, with an annotation, that Legate wasn't involved at the end - as it's supposed to.

But when a new thread is involved, apart from having said for() display neatly sequenced, I also get *both* annotations - that the Legate was *and* wasn't involved.

[image: result]

Why is control.InvokeRequired() acting like true and false at the same time? Why does

```
if(control.InvokeRequired == false)
        {
            control.Text = text + " (Legate not involved)";
        }
```

the "text" variable in this particular fragment seem empty? When it's being milled by delegate as "message" - it isn't. And finally, why, after deleting this part of the code completely, the control doesn't show any of the new data at all - even though it was supposed to pass through delegate already? Clearly something about the mechanics still eludes me and I can't put the finger on it. If someone could please explain, what is the real data flow in here.
Thanks!

Comment: You ask _Why is control.InvokeRequired() acting like true and false at the same time?_ - but it's **not** at the same time, one is after the other, so the state can of course change between the calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I also get both annotations - that the Legate was and wasn't involved.

You get both annotations because the code to each is executed.

You first get the `" (Legate involved)"` annotation because when the `PassToLegate()` method is first called, the code is executing in the wrong thread. I.e. `InvokeRequired` returns `true`. Thus the annotation is appended to the original `text` value passed to the method.

In that same block of code, you then call `control.Invoke(hat, new object[] {message});`. And the delegate variable `hat` has been initialized to `new Legate(PassToLegate);`. That causes the `PassToLegate()` method to be called again, but on the UI thread instead. The *new* `message` value, i.e. the `text` value with the `" (Legate involved)"` annotation appended, is passed as the parameter.

So the method is called a second time, this time on the UI thread. And in that case, the `InvokeRequired` is now `false`, and you add the annotation `" (Legate not involved)"`. Since the `text` parameter passed already had the `" (Legate involved)"` annotation appended to it, now both annotations are part of the string value assigned to the `Text` property.

For what it's worth, it is my opinion that the code should never bother with `InvokeRequired`. It is safe to call `Invoke()` when you are on the UI thread already (though of course ideally one would never do that), and so the `Invoke()` method itself has to do the equivalent of checking `InvokeRequired` anyway. You might as well just always call `Invoke()` all the time and keep the code simpler.

Even better would be to use higher-level abstractions such as `BackgroundWorker`, `Progress<T>`, and `async`/`await` (the last one being especially preferable when appropriate). Then you don't need to deal with the `Invoke()` method at all; the cross-thread invocations are handled automatically for you.